# Time varying-effect of smoking on BMI over time

Tags: panel-data, time-varying-covariate

I have a dataset with longitudinal measurements of BMI. The BMI for each participant is measured at 10 different time points. The aim of the study is to investigate how BMI evolves with time. Smoking status is recorded at each time point and is categorised as yes/no. I would like to study the effect of smoking on BMI with time as well. Smoking has been negatively associated with smoking and stopping usually results in weight gain. How do i capture the time-varying property of smoking in a single variable?

I tried to define the smoking variable as "ever smoked" and "never smoked", depending on whether they smoked at any time point or never smoked at all time points. But this doesnt capture the time-varying nature of the smoking status. I will be using a linear mixed model and random effects model

Comment: You could make this a Markov model, where each observation at time $t$ is the change in BMI versus $t-1$ regressed onto an indicator for smoking within that interval (clustered within subject)? Additional covariates for BMI absolute value and length of the interval may be useful here. Alternatively, depending on how far apart the observations are and how often subjects switch between smoking and not, is its effect that quick to appear? In my past we often worked with pack-years or indeed ever/never, also because self-reported smoking isn't always too reliable.

Comment: @PBulls I am not familiar with Markov models. The time scale is discretized with measurements occurring at fixed time points (annually), the data is unbalanced though.

Comment: Typically, this kind of situation calls for careful consideration of the residual covariance structure. That is one reason why @PBulls''s suggestion of a Markov model is a good idea. Alternatively you could fit a model with random effects for participants, and fixed effects for smoking status, time and their interaction (ie, a mixed effects model). In that case you should try to model the residual covariance through an autoregressive structure eg AR1. You can do this in R with the nmle package using generalise least squares (and maybe the glmmTMB package too), or in SAS with proc mixed.